# Number of partial orders that contain a specific relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

> Let be $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$
>
> Find the number of partial order relations of A that contain the relation $R=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$

I figured out that there is no easy way of counting partial orders, so I sketched all the possible Hasse diagrams (no way to check that out as far as I'm concerned) and then tried to count them by hand.

[image]
(1) We have **2** ways. $(1,2)$ up, $(3,4)$ down and viceversa.

(2) We have only **1** way.

(3) and (4) are equivalent, so they give me **2** ways.

(5) and (6) give me **2** ways too.

(7) Gives me 4 ways but 2 of them are mirrored, so **2** ways really.

So we have: $2+1+2+2+2 = 9$ partial orders containing $R=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$.

I don't have any way to check if I'm right, any help?

Comment: Does the assertion that $(1,2)$ is in the partial order mean that there is nothing between $1$ and $2$? I don't think so, else the usual total order on the rationals wouldn't contain any pairs at all. So you have not counted all the linear orders, let alone all of them.

Comment: There are six total orders (type 1) - 1234, 1324, 1342, 3124, 3142, 3412.

Comment: Right, I missed some at (1). My final result is 13 now, It's that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me count by a different way.  I will use $<$ for my partial order and say $x\sim y$ to mean that $x$ and $y$ are incomparable under $<$.

- $1<3$ and $2<4$ - There are **3** partial orders of this type: two total orders 
  based on $2<3$ or $3<2$ and one of your type 7 when $2\sim 3$.
- $3<1$ and $4<2$ - Essentially identical to above, with **3** more.
- $1<3$ and $4<2$ - Just **1** total order: $1<3<4<2$.
- $3<1$ and $2<4$ - Again, just **1**.
- $1\sim3$ and $2<4$ - Just **1**, of your type 3/4
- $1\sim3$ and $4<2$ - Again, just **1**.
- $1<3$ and $2\sim4$ - Just **1**, of your type 5/6
- $3<1$ and $2\sim4$ - Again, just **1**.
- $1\sim3$ and $2\sim4$ - Just **1**, of your type 2.

That's all 9 ways that $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$ can be related (or not related), which gives us a total of 13 total orders, as you did after your original miscount.